# Webmethod did not work with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using webmethod with Jquery. I have write a alert in success function and I got that alert when I run the project but My Webmthod did not call and So code is not work for me. I have put degub a point in Webmethod but it did not hit. I did not get any error nor my method call.
Below is my code of Jquery and Webmethod:

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
   function onDialogClosed(sender, args) {         

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",                  
                url: "SpellChecker.aspx/Save",
                data: { DocName: $("#txttest").val() },                
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert($("#txttest").val());  
                },
                error: function (a,b,c) {
                    alert(a+ b+ c);
                }
            });
        });

    }
```

WebMEthod :

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string Save(string DocName)
{
    try
    {
        GeneralDataTraveler objDataTraveller = new GeneralDataTraveler();
        objDataTraveller.Field1 = Convert.ToString(DocName);
        new ServiceCenter().SessionSetGeneralDataTraveller(objDataTraveller);
        return "HEllo";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you tried inspecting ajax with firebug, if so what was result.

Comment: are u creating webmethod in same page(.aspx) or in different .asmx file?

Comment: Hi @Dave:  I debugged code using firebug and i put debbuger in success and it debugger hit in success but my webmehtod did not work and one more thing (success: function (msg)) As msg I got whole html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below specifying content type, datatype and data as below format. It is working for me

```
 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       url: "order_form.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData", 
       data: '{DocName: "' + $("#txttest").val() + '" }', 
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data) { 
           //response(data.d);   
           alert('success');
       },
       error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
         alert(textStatus);
       } 
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following:

1.**Enable Webmethod** to be called from **Script** using:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

2.Enable the webservice **PAGE METHOD** to be called on page with scripting:

```
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Hope this helps!